# Submit form using specific button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a page with many forms and each form may has more than one submit button and each button has some actions "`onclick`" which specified by html.

I have created handler **onclick via jquery** for submit buttons which prevent default action and doing some work but then I need to submit this form. If i just simulate click on button - all actions triggered to **onclick** works once again.

Any ideas about it?

Abstract code example:

```
<form>
  <input type='submit' name='first_button' onclick='doSomething()'>
  <input type='submit' name='second_button' onclick='doSomethingElse()'>
<form>
```

Comment: can u post your code?

Comment: add specific and uniqe ids to each form, and than with jquery, when you listen for a click, submit the form you need to be submitted with $('#mysecondform').submit();

Comment: If you have `onclick` for each `submit` send `form id` as a parameter and submit that particular `form`!!

Answer (score 0):

Just call `referenceToFormElement.submit()`.

Since your submit buttons don't have values, you can't care about the server knowing which one was clicked, so bypassing them when submitting the form with JS will be fine.

```js
document.querySelector("[name=first_button]").addEventListener('click', doSomething);
document.querySelector("[name=second_button]").addEventListener('click', doSomethingElse);

function doSomething(e) {
  var button = this;
  e.preventDefault();
  setTimeout(function() {
    alert("Submitting A!");
    button.form.submit();
  }, 1000);
}

function doSomethingElse(e) {
  var button = this;
  e.preventDefault();
  setTimeout(function() {
    alert("Submitting B!");
    button.form.submit();
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type='submit' name='first_button'>
  <input type='submit' name='second_button'>
</form>

<p>(NB: This won't actually submit because it is on Stackoverflow: Blocked form submission to 'http://stacksnippets.net/js' because the form's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-forms' permission is not set.)
```

Comment: This can't be used to trigger a specific `formaction`